# I need help fetching user group codes and then showing post for those groups with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

The code I have works, but there is a problem I can't sort the data by ID because of the way that it's fetching the group codes. Here's the code:

```
function displayOverview(){
   global $database;
   global $session;
   $q = "SELECT username, group_code "
   ."FROM classes WHERE username = '".$session->username."'";
   $result = $database->query($q);
   /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
   $num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);
   if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)){
      echo "Error displaying info";
      return;
   }
   if($num_rows == 0){
      echo '<div id="container"><div id="float_left"><img src="profile_pics/default.gif" class="image3" width="50" height="50" border="0"></div>
        <div id="float_right"><div id="container2"><div class="bubble">
        <p class="user_name"></p>
        <p class="time">Error Name | <?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?></p>
        <p class="post">Error messages.</p>
        <!-- <p class="attachments"><img src="images/attachment.png" width="20" height="20"><b>Attatchmentments</b><br></p> -->
        </div></div></div></div>';
      return;
   }
   /* Display table contents */
   for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
       $group_code = mysql_result($result,$i,"group_code");
   $q2 = "SELECT id, username, post, date, group_code, type, attachment_1, attachment_2 "
   ."FROM posts WHERE group_code = '".$group_code."'";
   $result2 = $database->query($q2);
   /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
   $num_rows2 = mysql_numrows($result2);
   for($i2=0; $i2<$num_rows2; $i2++){
       $uname2  = mysql_result($result2,$i2,"username");
       $post = mysql_result($result2,$i2,"post");
       $type = mysql_result($result2,$i2,"type");
      $userinfo2  = $database->getUserInfo2($uname2);
      $userinfo3  = $database->getUserInfo3($uname2);
      $full_name = $userinfo2['full_name'];
      $profile_img = $userinfo2['profile_img'];
   }
  }
}
```

I have am completely stuck, is there another way to retrieve the group codes then call the MYSQL database and find out what groups the user is in and only return post for those groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one query, by `JOIN`ing the two tables like this:

```
SELECT
  c.username,
  c.group_code,
  p.id,
  p.post, 
  p.date,
  p.type,
  ...
FROM classes AS c
INNER JOIN posts AS p ON c.group_code = p.group_code
WHERE c.username = ...
ORDER BY p.Id;
```

Comment: @NarvinJavonWilliams - You're welcome any time, and welcome to stackoverflow :) Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thank you and I have a question is there a way you could write this in a php for me like how I had the other query as $q because when I added $session->username it returned error displaying results.

Comment: @NarvinJavonWilliams - You should have only one query, this one instead of two queries, and add this condition of the `$session->username` to the `WHERE` clause, then execute it the same way you did for the queries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question, but you can sort in SQL by adding:

```
... ORDER BY field [ASC/DESC]
```

Or you can sort in PHP using [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) .